# is the global constant cannot be use in while loops?

Tags: python, while-loop, constants

is the global constant cannot be use in while loops?

```
EASY_ATTEMP = 10 
HARD_ATTEMP = 5 
random_number = random.randint(1, 100)
difficulty = "easy"
if difficulty == "easy":
  attemp = EASY_ATTEMP

already_finished = False

while not already_finished:
  print(f"You have {attemp} attempts reamaining to guess the number")  #<--here
  guess = int(input("Make a guess: "))
```

And the its show the error like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 21, in <module>
    print(f"You have {attemp} attempts reamaining to guess the number")
NameError: name 'attemp' is not defined
```

What is going on?

Comment: What happens if `difficulty` is not `easy`?

Comment: IDK WHAT HAPPEND BUT NOW THE ERROR HAS GONE!

Comment: This code doesn't cause that error.  What are you expecting the value of `attemp` to be if `difficulty` is anything other than `"easy"` though?

Answer (score 0):

I copied the code and tried run it but got no errors. I don't know what the problem is but I would suggest to make your code neater.
'''

```
attemp = 5
random_number = random.randint(1, 100)
difficulty = input('Do you want easy difficulty? Y or N?')
if difficulty in  "Yy":
    attemp = 10

while attemp > 0:
    print(f"You have {attemp} attempts reamaining to guess the number")  #<--here
    guess = int(input("Make a guess: "))
    if guess == random_number:
        break
    attemp -= 1
```

'''

For example, in the while loop, you can create a boolean with the attempt variable and reduce the number by one for ever iteration. The variable 'attemp' will always evaluate to an easy difficulty because the variable *difficulty* is always referencing the 'easy' str. I'm not sure how you want the code to run but in the above code I set it so that the user can decide.